# SDP protocol: attribute recvonly, who will receive?

Tags: sdp

I am developing an SDP packet parser and creator. If attribute a is set to recvonly like

```
a=recvonly
```

person A sent this attribute to the server S. Then who will open the connection in receive only mode? Person A or server S?

Similarly if person A set 'a' attribute to 'sendrecv' and server only accepts the connection in sendonly mode what to do here ?

Comment: Not actually answering your question, but have you seen this https://github.com/beradrian/sdpparser. I developed this parser and I would appreciate your opinion.

Comment: actually i dont how to use github projects :( node.js is pretty good and easy to use platform but github i dont get it.

Comment: github is only for hosting your source code, but you can get the parser from here too: https://www.npmjs.com/package/sdpparser and add it in your `package.json` dependencies.

Comment: @AdrianBer Thank you so much for the help. Any good parser like that for rtp ? i want get the data within an rtp packet and store it. ?

Comment: Sorry, none that I know of.

Comment: @AdrianBer okay. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I have got the answer for the first question. If person A sends 'a=recvonly' person A will open the connection in 'sendonly' mode and server S will open the connection in 'recvonly' mode. As stated in [RFC 4566 Section 6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4566#section-6).